# How to compare two (2) unequal dataframes in Python and assign elements from the one to another?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append, comparison

I am a python beginner and I have this issue. I define the following two datasets.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([10, 20, 30]),
               columns=['number1'])
df1
       number1
0       10
1       20
2       30


df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[5, 6, 10, 12, 20, 25, 30, 50], [12.3, 15.5, 17.8, 19.0, 25, 18, 18.4, 15.8], [15.3, 18.5, 17.8, 11.0, 28, 17, 19.5, 11.1]]),
                   index=['number1', 'start', 'end']).T
df2
   number1  start   end
0      5.0   12.3  15.3
1      6.0   15.5  18.5
2     10.0   17.8  17.8
3     12.0   19.0  11.0
4     20.0   25.0  28.0
5     25.0   18.0  17.0
6     30.0   18.4  19.5
7     50.0   15.8  11.1
```

What I would like to do is to add `start` and `end` columns to `df1` dataframe containing the corresponding elements of `df2`. (if and only if number1==number1). The expected output is the following:

```
   number1  start   end
0     10.0   17.8  17.8
1     20.0   25.0  28.0
2     30.0   18.4  19.5
```

I appended two (2) empty columns to the `df1`.
Please note that two datasets are unequal. I followed this solution. However I got this warning.

```
def equal(df1, df2, ignore_index=True):
    if df1['number1'].values == df2['number1'].values:
        df1['start'].values = df2['start'].values
        df1['end'].values = df2['end'].values


 <ipython-input-47-7137be14ffba>:2: DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.
      if df1['number1'].values == df2['number1'].values:
```

**Do you have any suggestions?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `df.merge()`:

```
In [240]: res = df1.merge(df2, on='number1')

In [241]: res
Out[241]: 
   number1  start   end
0       10   17.8  17.8
1       20   25.0  28.0
2       30   18.4  19.5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply merge the two data frames

```
df1.merge(df2)

number1 start   end
0   10  17.8    17.8
1   20  25.0    28.0
2   30  18.4    19.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use df.merge (df2)

It should give you the answer your looking for